# InvalidCastException from selecting ListBoxItem's Contents

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, listboxitem

My ListBoxItems contain multiple TextBoxes like this:

```
<ListBox Name="myList" SelectionChanged="myList_SelectionChanged">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ListBoxItem>
                        <ListBoxItem.Content>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">

                                <TextBlock Name="nameTextBlock" 
                                       Text="{Binding Name}" 
                                       />

                                <TextBlock Name="ageTextBlock" 
                                       Text="{Binding Age}" 
                                       />

                                <TextBlock Name="genderTextBlock" 
                                       Text="{Binding Gender}" 
                                       />

                                <TextBlock Name="heightTextBlock" 
                                       Text="{Binding Height}" 
                                       />

                            </StackPanel>
                        </ListBoxItem.Content>
                    </ListBoxItem>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

When an item is clicked, I would like each TextBlock to be saved to IsolatedStorage under corresponding keys.  Right now the closest I've gotten to this method is this:

```
private void mysList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ListBoxItem lbi = (ListBoxItem)myList.SelectedItem;
        appSettings["name"] = (string)lbi.Content;
    }
```

But, when clicked I get an InvalidCastException.  As I understand it, it's basically due to me trying to convert all four textboxes into a single string (or something like that).  So how do I save each TextBox's text field independently within the ListBoxItem to an IsolatedStorage key/value?  Thanks again in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you populate your `ListBox` by setting `ItemsSource` property, `SelectedItem` will have a reference to your `class object`, not `ListBoxItem`.

For example you have assigned `ObservableCollection<Person>` to `ItemsSource`,

Following code will do the trick:

```
private void mysList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Person p = (Person)myList.SelectedItem;
    appSettings["name"] = String.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}", p.Name, p.Age, p.Gender, p.Height);
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much.  However, say I wanted to save the the name under appSettings["name"], age under appSettings["age"] and so on.  Could I do that as well?  Or do they all have to be filed under one key?

Comment: Of course you can. Given that there are available keys in your `appSettings` dictionary.

Comment: Sorry, I kind of jumped the gun on that question.  Got it figured out no problem.  Thanks again!